# How can I handle a POST from a third party authentication when I need a GET in AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cloudfront, serverless, aws-lambda-edge

I am using AWS Cloudfront to serve static html and images from a private s3 bucket. I need an authentication layer and have a requirement to use Microsoft SSO. To trigger the authentication check, I have a Lambda function connected to a Cloudfront Viewer Request.

From what I understand, I need to return the Request in a callback method when I want to get past the viewer request (after authentication). My issue is that the Microsoft SSO redirect's to the Cloudfront URL using an HTTP POST. If I return the request, Cloudfront attempts to POST to an S3 (or sends a MethodNotAllowed when I disable POST). I need this to be a GET request, but do not know how I can change it. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html), the HTTP of the request object is read only.

I have tried redirecting to the Cloudfront URL when posting or serving a simple HTML that links to the html I want, but these both result in the Viewer Request being called again.

Has anyone handled a similar situation?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return a redirect, but set the status code to `303` instead of one of the other 3xx codes.  This is `See Other` which results in the browser following the redirect but using `GET` on the second request.  There is no way to trick CloudFront into believing the method changed -- a redirect is required.